# Can't get AVFoundation to work with AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto resolution

Tags: image-processing, opencv, uiimage, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I can't seem to get the pixel alignment to work with AVFoundation in AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto resolution.  Pixel alignment works fine with lower resolution like AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 (AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720_Picture).[image: AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720_picture][image: AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto_picture]

Specifically, when I uncomment these lines:
    if ([captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto]) {
        [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to set resolution to AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto");
    }
I get a missed aligned image as shown in the 2nd image below.  Any comments/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Here's my code to set up the 1) capture session, 2) delegate callback, and 3) save one steaming image to verify pixel alignment.
1.  Capture Session set up

```
    - (void)InitCaptureSession {
captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
if ([captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720]) {
    [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720];        
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unable to set resolution to AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720");
}

//    if ([captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto]) {
//        [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];        
//    } else {
//        NSLog(@"Unable to set resolution to AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto");
//    }

captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
videoInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:nil];

AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *captureOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
captureOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES; 

dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_queue_create("cameraQueue", NULL);
[captureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
dispatch_release(queue);
NSString* key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey; 
    NSNumber* value = [NSNumber     numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange];
NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key];     
[captureOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettings]; 

[captureSession addInput:videoInput];
[captureSession addOutput:captureOutput];
    [captureOutput release];

    previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.captureSession];
[previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

    CALayer *rootLayer = [previewView layer];// self.view.layer; //

[rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[previewLayer setFrame:[rootLayer bounds]];
[rootLayer addSublayer:previewLayer];
[captureSession startRunning];  
}


- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
   fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection 
{ 

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
static int processedImage = 0;
processedImage++;
if (processedImage==100) {
    [self SaveImage:sampleBuffer]; 
}

[pool drain];
} 

// Create a UIImage CMSampleBufferRef and save for verifying pixel alignment
- (void) SaveImage:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer 
{
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0); 
CvSize imageSize;
imageSize.width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); ;
imageSize.height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 
IplImage *image = cvCreateImage(imageSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);     
void *y_channel = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0); 
char *tempPointer = image->imageData;
memcpy(tempPointer, y_channel, image->imageSize);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:image->imageData length:image->imageSize];
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(image->width, image->height,
                                    8, 8, image->width,
                                    colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                                    provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
UIImage *Saveimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(Saveimage, nil, nil, nil);
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within `SaveImage`, the 5th argument of `CGImageCreate` is `bytesPerRow` and you should not pass `image->width` since the number of bytes per row may differ in case of memory alignment. This is the case with the `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` where `width = 852` (w/ an iPhone 4 camera) while the number of bytes per row for the 1-st plane (Y) is `864` since it is 16-bytes aligned.

1/ You should get the bytes per row as follow:

```
size_t bpr = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
```

2/ Then take care to take into account the bytes per row while copying the pixels to your `IplImage`:

```
char *y_channel = (char *) CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);

// row by row copy
for (int i = 0; i < image->height; i++)
  memcpy(tempPointer + i*image->widthStep, y_channel + i*bpr, image->width);
```

You can keep the `[NSData dataWithBytes:image->imageData length:image->imageSize];` as is since `image->imageSize` takes into account the alignment (`imageSize = height*widthStep`).

3/ At last pass the `IplImage` width step as `CGImageCreate` 5-th parameter:

```
CGImageCreate(image->width, image->height, 8, 8, image->widthStep, ...);
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head.  I owe you a couple beers at least.  How did you know the y-plane is 16-bytes aligned?  Was it in a document somewhere and I totally missed it?

Comment: Forgot to mention about changing y_channel to char*  `(char *) y_channel = (char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);` so the compiler doesn't complain about performing arithmetic on void pointer

Comment: Good catch! I've edited the question. Regarding the memory alignement: this is a best practice when manipulating images + the API-s of both `CGImage` and `CVPixelBufferRef` include explicitly the mention to the bytes-per-row (row bytes of the pixel storage memory). At last the Quartz2D programming guide indicates: *Tip:  When you create a bitmap graphics context, you’ll get the best performance if you make sure the data and bytesPerRow are 16-byte aligned.*